# QTP - Getting a button value

Tags: button, testing, automated-tests, qtp, utf

I have a portion of code where I pick the value in a button and use it for other purposes. Or, at least, this is what I'd like to do.

The button changes value at every refresh of the page (it's a webpage). 
For example: at the first access the button's value (or label) is "Results List (51)" but, if I refresh the page, the value becomes "Results List (11)". 
What changes is the number inside the brackets (that identifies the number of results inside the list). 
This is the code interested:

```
    ok = Browser("Bwr").Page("Page").Frame("Frame").WebButton("name:=Results List OK").GetToProperty("name")
    ko = Browser("Bwr").Page("Page").Frame("Frame").WebButton("name:=Results List KO").GetToProperty("name")

    If InStr(ko, "0") > 0 and Instr(ok, "0")=0 Then 
        reporter.ReportEvent 0, "Riabbinamento effettuato", "Operazione effettuata con esito positivo: tutte le misure sono state riabbinate"
        else reporter.ReportEvent 1, "Riabbinamento fallito", "Operazione effettuata con esito negativo: ci sono misure su cui l'operazione è fallita"
    End If
```

Don't pay attention to the reporter (I'm Italian, it's written in my language).
If I execute the above code QTP puts in ok the string "Results List OK" but I want to put in ok the string "Results List OK (n)" (with n being the number that changes at every refresh of the page). 
Basically I only need the number inside the brackets in order to make the IF truly works...

Any idea?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok problem solved. 
I've used GetRoProperty instead of GetToProperty and modified the value in the brackets after WebElement from "name:=Results List OK" to "name:=Results List OK.*"

Thanks to gigatropolis for the useful tips (I upvoted your answer) but it was only half the solution :)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a regular expression to map the property.
Result List (\d+)
 or just Result List.*

Comment: tried but when I check ko contains "Results List.*"... I want it to be like "Results List(6)"...